# 2D Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I want to compute the following  2D Fourier transform for the following matrix \begin{equation}u=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
10 & 0 & 0 \\
10 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\end{equation}

And I don't know which are the coefficients N and M from the formula of Fourier.
Since:

\begin{equation}c_{k, p}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} x(n, m) e^{-2 \pi i\left(\frac{k n}{N}+\frac{p m}{M}\right)}, \quad k=0,1, \ldots, N-1 \cdot p=0,1, \ldots, M-1\end{equation}